# WP7: Checking for user credentials on startup and loading different view?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Can anyone help. I have created a small WP7 and its working the way i want it to.

It always asks the user for username and password to enter the application, I also have a button called "Remember Settings", if this is checked the next time the application is loaded i would like it to login autoamtically hence the user will not see the login screen and it will bypass this view and load another.

I need some way to load 1 xaml is the user credentials don't exist or are not valid and another the main app xaml if credential exists and are valid.

It appears that the loading of the page is hardcoded in the manifast. As you can see i am loading my LoginPage.

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="LoginPage.xaml"/>
</Tasks>
```

SO what would my best way of accomplishing this, I thought of changing creating xaml (entance file) where i could check in the constructor of my VIEWMODEL if the credentials exists etc and then do a navigateTo another page. But this feels like code smell..

Can anyone help with advise or examples of the best way of accomplishing this.

I am actually using MVVM Light but things should be pretty much the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do by storing user credentials in ISOLATED STORAGE of windows phone 7. Once User checks remember settings or credentials checkbox then you save these settings in isolated storage. And Next Time As Your Application Launches And Suppose Your Default Page is "MainPage.XAML". Then On This Page OnPageNavigated Event Check For User Settings. If Settings There Then Redirect To User on Other View (Logged View). Otherwise User Will Be On MainPage.xaml. And Logout Button You Can Clear These Settings..

Here is Good Example Here For ISOLATED Storage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229120 (Example Code)

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Correct Martin its OnPageNavigatedTo.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the username, password, authtokens or any other value which you need to check for authentication in settings.

On opening of login page, check the value of your token from settings in the OnNavigatedTo method. If its not null, it means user is already logged in, then you can redirect him to you Home screen else show the login page and ask him to enter the credentials.

Also don't forget to save the settings on app exit. Check this link below for further help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510(v=VS.92).aspx

On Logout, clear the tokens in the settings page